# Select the most recent record with groupby in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables entries similar as follows:

```
gym_clients
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|      id | first_name|     last_name |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
|      1  |  Name 1   |        Last 1 |
|      2  |  Name 2   |        Last 2 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+

gym_client_purchases

+---------+---------+-----------------+
|      id | client_id | purchase_date |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
|      15 |       1   |    2018-04-01 |
|      16 |       1   |    2018-05-01 |
|      17 |       2   |    2018-05-01 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
```

I want to group by the purchases of each client and show the latest.

I tried this query but the groupby shows me the oldest purchase (id 15).

any ideas?

```
 $this->data['latestSubscriptions'] = GymPurchase::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'gym_client_purchases.*')
              ->leftJoin('gym_clients', 'gym_clients.id', '=', 'client_id')
              ->groupBy('gym_client_purchases.client_id')
              ->orderBy('gym_client_purchases.purchase_date', 'desc')
              ->get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My brain's not hitting on all cylinders, but you need a max(purchase_date) in the mix somehow.  Your `group by` might be grouping, but you need some sort of aggregate function to reduce it to one row.  Not sure how that works in MySQL because I work in DB2...

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly calling the table names to specify their columns, isn't that supposed to be the same on the **ON** clause? on your code it's  like this

```
$this->data['latestSubscriptions'] = GymPurchase::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'gym_client_purchases.*')
      //client_id here isn't specified
      ->leftJoin('gym_clients', 'gym_clients.id', '=', 'client_id')
      ->groupBy('gym_client_purchases.client_id')
      ->orderBy('gym_client_purchases.purchase_date', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

It should be like this:

```
$this->data['latestSubscriptions'] = GymPurchase::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'gym_client_purchases.*')
      ->leftJoin('gym_clients', 'gym_clients.id', '=', 'gym_client_purchases.client_id')
      ->groupBy('gym_client_purchases.client_id')
      ->orderBy('gym_client_purchases.purchase_date', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

I tested your code, it should be working properly due to the orderby descending, I think just a little typo on your code snippets

Answer (score 0):

First, when you use group by you have o specify in this clause the columns for which the query is gioing to group, so I suggest to you to try you query on sql engine.

You will have something like this

```
select first_name, last_name, A.*
from gym_client_purchases A
left Join gym_clients B on B.id = A.client_id
group by A.client_id
order By A.purchase_date desc
```

and you will notice that it doesn't work

Maybe what you want is something like this

```
select A.client_id, B.first_name, B.last_name, max(A.purchase_date)
from gym_client_purchases A
left Join gym_clients B on B.id = A.client_id
group by A.client_id, B.first_name, B.last_name
order By max(A.purchase_date) desc
```